# C# WPF Class Property resetting to null

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to simply log the user in, save the validated user name to a class called 'User', property called 'Name' using get set accessors.

Using breakpoints i understand that the value is set correctly in the login page but when i open up the Dashboard page - I just want to change the text of a label to say "Welcome, " + User.Name;

However the value is always null when I try to access it, I am out of ideas!

User Class

```
namespace Thor_Hours_Calculator
{
    public class User

    {
        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Login Page

```
string Username = usernameTxt.Text;
user = new User();
user.Name = usernameTxt.Text;
```

Dashboard

```
User NewUser = new User();
string username = NewUser.Name;
welcomemsg.Content += username;
```

Comment: Are able to pass the user object from Login page to dash board? can you show this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of `NewUser` in the dashboard. You can't expect this instance to have a `Name` set.

You should pass the instance that you create in the login page to the dashboard or save it somewhere where it can be accessed. The other option would be to make the property static:

```
public static class User
{
    public static string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Login Page:

```
User.Name = usernameTxt.Text;
```

Dashboard:

```
string username = User.Name;
```

Comment: Thankyou! Silly mistake I've only just come back to C# after a while forgetting the basics...